# greeter stuck after adding new user

Tags: release-loki, greeter

Installed Loki over the weekend; first Linux install here at home in a decade. After adding a "user" profile (in addition to my "admin" user), I find I'm stuck logging in under my "user" profile at the greeter prompt. I can su to my admin profile and try to fix stuff, but it's quite annoying to feel locked out of a fresh install.

I see icons for three profiles: my "user" (with functional password field), my inaccessible "admin" and guest accounts. I can click around with the mouse; processor isn't busy; the other icons simply don't respond. The clock updates, I see the wifi icon, and I can suspend or shutdown from the right top corner menu.

Using the package manager I tried reinstalling greeter - no change.

Suggestions? Since I don't see this popping up elsewhere I'm guessing it's an issue on my end - not an elementary bug.

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue on freya which was caused by a trojan. I used clamtk to get rid of it but I accidentally wiped my user system share files by over-vigilance and couldn't load the profile at login. I'm looking for a way to restore that profiles ability to share the system files now.
I can enter login details on that profile but it won't load. It's my user profile, the admin works ok.  Did you change any system permissions when you installed it? It's definitely permissions for me.